# Is the serviceAutoStartProvider attribute required to auto-start an ASP.NET application?

Tags: iis, asp.net, iis-7.5, application-pools, .net-4.0

I've been reading [Scott Guthrie's post on Auto-Start ASP.NET Applications](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx), which provides examples on how to setup an ASP.NET 4.0 application to auto-start.

```xml
<applicationPools>
    <add name="MyAppWorkerProcess" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0"
        startMode="AlwaysRunning" />
</applicationPools>

<!--...-->
<sites>
     <site name="MySite" id="1">
          <application path="/" serviceAutoStartEnabled="true"
              serviceAutoStartProvider="PreWarmMyCache" />
     </site>
</sites>

<!--...-->
<serviceAutoStartProviders>
     <add name="PreWarmMyCache" type="PreWarmCache, MyAssembly" />
</serviceAutoStartProviders>
```

What is unclear from his post is if the following configuration will auto-start an ASP.NET application:

```xml
<applicationPools>
    <add name="MyAppWorkerProcess" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0"
        startMode="AlwaysRunning" />
</applicationPools>

<!--...-->
<sites>
     <site name="MySite" id="1">
          <application path="/" serviceAutoStartEnabled="true" />
     </site>
</sites>
```

The difference here is that there is no class specified to start-up. Ideally the application would just be loaded. The documentation on [Application for a Site](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application)  implies that the `serviceAutoStartEnabled` attribute requires a `serviceAutoStartProvider` attribute to work. But there is no indication of what happens if the additional attribute is not provided.

- Am I reading the documentation correctly?
- Is a `serviceAutoStartProvider` required to be specified to utilize `serviceAutoStartEnabled`?
- What happens if no `serviceAutoStartProvider` is specified?

Answer (score 10):

The Warm-Up functions, specifically those related to IIS were either discontinued or no longer developed against.  Scott's article was from pre-VS2010.  They re-wrote the entire stack into a new IIS Module.

You can now configure all of this directly from IIS using the [Application Initialization Module](http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationInitialization).  The module provides more features and functionality than the warm-up mechanism you are looking into.

Comment: Off to play with this the [Application Initialization Module](http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationInitialization), but I imagine I'll be marking this as the accepted answer soon. Thanks for replying, I hate when questions languish, figured I was going to earn the Tumbleweed badge on this one! ;)

Comment: @ahsteele Ha, eventually people troll through the old questions.  Just takes some time every once in a while.  Hope it fill the void for you.